# Database query in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a table named "news" containing the following details:
id, title, slug, text

As such, I used the following code to retrieve the whole "news" table from my database.

```
public function get_news($slug = FALSE)
        {
            if ($slug === FALSE)
            {
                $query = $this->db->get('news');
                return $query->result_array();
            }

            $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));
            return $query->row_array();
        }
```

Displaying the result

```
<?php foreach ($news as $news_item): ?>

                <h3><?php echo $news_item['title']; ?></h3>
                <div class="main">
                        <?php echo $news_item['text']; ?>
                </div>
                <p><a href="<?php echo site_url('news/'.$news_item['slug']); ?>">View article</a></p>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

How should I go about to change the code in order to get the query result of "select title, text from news;"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$query = $this->db->select('title, text,')->from('news')->get();
```

and with `where`:

```
 $query = $this->db->select('title, text,')->from('news')->where('slug', $slug)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
May I know if I want to perform this query "select title from news where text='me'"
does it correspond to the query statement below?
$query = $this->db->select('title')->from('news')->where('text', 1)->get();

Comment: Yes, but at `where('text', 1)` why 1? Should be `where('text', 'me')`. Also please mark my answer as valid.